# Difficult Compounding Probabilities Problem (Though Independent, the Previous Probabilities MUST be considered).

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I could really use some help solving this problem. Here is the fact pattern:

There are four (4) balls in a bag from which to choose (A, B, C, & D). The picking is 100% random, so the probability of choosing any of the balls is equal (1 out of 4, or 25%). One (1) ball will be chosen during each draw. After each draw, the chosen ball is put back. There will be a total of six (6) draws, all of which are 100% independent of one another. Your job is to find the probability of choosing each ball BEFORE each draw.

** Even though these events are independent of one another, each next draw will take into account the probabilities of the previous draw(s). HINT: Probability of rolling a die and getting a three (3) is 1/6. The probability of rolling the die and getting a three (3) again is (1/6) x (1/6) = 1/36. And the probability of rolling the die again and getting another three (3) is (1/6) x (1/6) x (1/6) = 1/216.

On the first draw, ball A was chosen.
On the second draw, ball A was chosen.
On the third draw, ball B was chosen.
On the fourth draw, ball C was chosen.
On the fifth draw, ball A was chosen.
On the sixth draw, ball D was chosen.

Question 1: BEFORE the first draw, what is the probability of choosing balls A through D?

Question 2 – AFTER the first draw, but BEFORE the second draw, what is the probability of choosing balls A through D in the second draw?

Question 3 – AFTER the second draw, but BEFORE the third draw, what is the probability of choosing balls A through D in the third draw?

Question 4 – AFTER the third draw, but BEFORE the fourth draw, what is the probability of choosing balls A through D in the fourth draw?

Question 5 – AFTER the fourth draw, but BEFORE the fifth draw, what is the probability of choosing balls A through D in the fifth draw?

Question 6 – AFTER the fifth draw, but BEFORE the sixth draw, what is the probability of choosing balls A through D in the sixth draw?

Question 7 – AFTER the sixth draw, but BEFORE the next draw, what is the probability of choosing balls A through D in the next draw?

Comment: I don't think the probabilities have to be considered previously. Since the ball you take from each draw is put back in, each ball has the same probability of being chosen again.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what is asked for, and why similar things are asked for so many times. Let our sample space consist of the $4^6$ words of length $6$ over the alphabet A, B, C, D.

I would guess that (for the second draw) the following (totally unnecessary) argument is wanted.

After the first draw, the total number of possible outcomes is $(1)(4^5)$, and they are all equally likely. The number of possible outcomes in which the second ball is, say, B is $(1)(1)(4^4)$. So the probability that the second ball is B, given that the first ball was A, is $\frac{(1)(1)(4^4)}{(1)(4^5)}$. Of course this simplifies to $\frac{1}{4}$.